# Real PR2 plug and unplug procedure

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We now have a PR2 in our lab and we are cautiously reading the tutorials and learning how to use it the right way. But in our search, we were unable to find a clear information about the way to plug and unplug the PR2 to the mains. I read that it is recommended to let the robot plugged when not used, but what about the plug and unplug procedures ? Are there particular things to know about this point ?

Thanks for reading,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81566/real-pr2-plug-and-unplug-procedure/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the PR2 Manual (http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter3):

```
When plugging in the PR2, always attach the power cord to the AC inlet on the robot before attaching it to the AC outlet on the wall. Unplug the cord from the wall before unplugging from the robot.
```

Plugging a live AC cord into the back of the robot can cause arcing, which can deteriorate the power inlet on the PR2.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-21**:
It should be noted that that's actually happened, so it's not just some theoretical safety advise.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-09-22**:
Thanks for your answer and sharing your experience. I finally found this quotation in the manual after asking the question. I think It should be more visible on the online documentation (as it is a safety procedure and should not appear only there : http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter3#What.27s_in_the_box)